# Problem with GLM to regress on the product of one numeric variable and one categorical variable

Tags: r, glm

I would like to perform a logistic regression on the following model:

```
regression <- Y ~ 
netSales + size + CashAssetRatio + FRNG + 
  I(insolvency * countryCode)
```

With the following code:

```
tbmodel <- glm(regression, data=trainSplit, 
               weights=NULL, binomial(link = "logit"), 
           na.action=na.omit) 
###### REPRENDRE ICI APRES PAUSE
```

However, when I compute the regression I get the following error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
>   les contrastes ne peuvent être appliqués qu'aux facteurs ayant au
>   moins deux niveaux In addition: Warning message: In
>   Ops.factor(insolvency, countryIsoCode) : ‘*’ not meaningful for
>   factors

The fact is that I don't where it could come from because my variable countryCode is a factor with more than 2 levels and I have no NA. Here are some data:

```
             countryCode insolvency  netSales Y size CashAssetRatio         FRNG
47091             FR       0.0491 -0.04042249 0  2       1.123095       -0.001679786
24460             IT       0.0115 -0.04343820 0  1       1.078720       -0.001130815
11921             FR       0.0029 -0.04227984 0  2       1.076595       -0.001097954
1657              FR       0.0016 -0.04242885 0  2       1.075237       -0.001075071
37572             IT       0.0006 -0.04355702 0  1       1.077884       -0.001122143
8155              FR       0.0270 -0.04058710 0  2       1.076638       -0.001067854
```

Do you have an idea? Thank you

Comment: Please put your data into a form that people can use to run the code, probably using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ?formula

> While formulae usually involve just variable and factor names, they
>   can also involve arithmetic expressions. The formula log(y) ~ a +
>   log(x) is quite legal. When such arithmetic expressions involve
>   operators which are also used symbolically in model formulae, there
>   can be confusion between arithmetic and symbolic operator use.
>
> To avoid this confusion, the function I() can be used to bracket those
>   portions of a model formula where the operators are used in their
>   arithmetic sense. For example, in the formula y ~ a + I(b+c), the term
>   b+c is to be interpreted as the sum of b and c.

So your formula as written is literally asking for multiplication.  Since what you want is an iteraction, remove the `I()`.